# Dart/Flutter Add an Image to AlertDialog Text Field

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-alertdialog, flutter-text

I have an Application where I want Users to be able to buy Power Ups inside an Alert Dialog.

For the actual buying, the user simply presses the IconButton, which already works.

Is there a way to display the Images also in the Text above, instead of the actual text?

So for example the TNT image used in the Icon Button to also display in the text instead of the actual word "TNT"?

```
AlertDialog(
              title: const Text('Buy power up?'),
              content: Text(
                  'Do you want to buy \nTNT for $tntPrice\$ \nMine for $minePrice\$ \nWrapped for $wrappedPrice\$?'),
              elevation: 24,
              shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(16))),
              actions: <Widget>[
                IconButton(
                    icon: Image.asset('assets/images/bombs/tnt.png'),
                    onPressed: () => buyPowerUp("tnt", tntPrice, coinBloc,
                        reportingBloc, gameBloc, context)),
                IconButton(
                    icon: Image.asset('assets/images/bombs/mine.png'),
                    onPressed: () => buyPowerUp("mine", minePrice, coinBloc,
                        reportingBloc, gameBloc, context)),
                IconButton(
                    icon: Image.asset('assets/images/bombs/multi_color.png'),
                    onPressed: () => buyPowerUp("wrapped", wrappedPrice,
                        coinBloc, reportingBloc, gameBloc, context)),
                TextButton(
                  onPressed: () => buyPowerUp(
                      "nothing", 0, coinBloc, reportingBloc, gameBloc, context),
                  child: const Text('Start Game'),
                )
              ],
            ));
```

---

[image]

So basically that it looks like this(Sry for bad image, just used paint to make it clear)

[image]

Comment: What do you exact want ? can you draw/put your wanted image

Comment: Yes, i edited the question, i hope that it is more understandable now! Thank you

Comment: Check my below [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72198341/13997210) hope its helpful to you.

Comment: If you want your icons as action see my updated answer and just unComment the action code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
  AlertDialog(
              title: const Text('Buy power up?'),
              content: Wrap(
            children: [
              Text('Do you want to buy'),
              Row(
                children: [
                  Image.asset('assets/images/bombs/tnt.png'),
                  SizedBox(width: 5),
                  Text(
                      ' for $tntPrice\$'),
                ],
              ),
              Row(
                children: [
                  Image.asset('assets/images/bombs/mine.png'),
                  SizedBox(width: 5),
                  Text(
                      ' for $minePrice\$'),
                ],
              ),
              Row(
                children: [
                  Image.asset('assets/images/bombs/multi_color.png'),
                  SizedBox(width: 5),
                  Text(
                      ' for $wrappedPrice\$?'),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          )
                  elevation: 24,
                  shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(16))),
                  actions: <Widget>[
                    IconButton(
                        icon: Image.asset('assets/images/bombs/tnt.png'),
                        onPressed: () => buyPowerUp("tnt", tntPrice, coinBloc,
                            reportingBloc, gameBloc, context)),
                    IconButton(
                        icon: Image.asset('assets/images/bombs/mine.png'),
                        onPressed: () => buyPowerUp("mine", minePrice, coinBloc,
                            reportingBloc, gameBloc, context)),
                    IconButton(
                        icon: Image.asset('assets/images/bombs/multi_color.png'),
                        onPressed: () => buyPowerUp("wrapped", wrappedPrice,
                            coinBloc, reportingBloc, gameBloc, context)),
                    TextButton(
                      onPressed: () => buyPowerUp(
                          "nothing", 0, coinBloc, reportingBloc, gameBloc, context),
                      child: const Text('Start Game'),
                    )
                  ],
                ));
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this works very nice, but now i have the problem that the Alert Dialog is way too big, is there a way to fix that? https://ibb.co/FsKKSRD

Comment: Just use Wrap widget instead of Column

Comment: Now it works perfect thanks, one more question, is there a way to make the images the same size as the text? Because now i have to manually set the images to height: 25, is there a way to fit it to the same size?

Comment: I don't think that there is a better way than to set height for image.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean like this ?

```
return AlertDialog(
    title: const Text('Buy power up?'),
    content: Wrap(
      children: [
        Text('Do you want to buy'),
        Image.asset('assets/images/bombs/multi_color.png'),
        Text('for 100'),
        Image.asset('assets/images/bombs/multi_color.png'),
        Text('for 200'),
        Image.asset('assets/images/bombs/multi_color.png'),
        Text('for 1000'),
        // Image.asset('assets/images/bombs/tnt.png')
      ],
    ),
    elevation: 24,
    shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(16))),
    actions: <Widget>[
      IconButton(
          icon: Image.asset('assets/images/bombs/tnt.png'),
          onPressed: () => buyPowerUp("tnt", tntPrice, coinBloc,
              reportingBloc, gameBloc, context)),
      IconButton(
          icon: Image.asset('assets/images/bombs/mine.png'),
          onPressed: () => buyPowerUp("mine", minePrice, coinBloc,
              reportingBloc, gameBloc, context)),
      IconButton(
          icon: Image.asset('assets/images/bombs/multi_color.png'),
          onPressed: () => buyPowerUp("wrapped", wrappedPrice,
              coinBloc, reportingBloc, gameBloc, context)),
      TextButton(
        onPressed: () => buyPowerUp(
            "nothing", 0, coinBloc, reportingBloc, gameBloc, context),
        child: const Text('Start Game'),
      )
    ]
);
```

Comment: This kind of works, but i actually don't want them to be IconButtons in the actual text

Comment: Okay so u don't need click in the actual text, i edited my answer, u may check it again

Comment: The problem with the wrap is that i can not really make a newline after the price. So the whole text including the images is in the same line, but the answer from Gejaa works perfect, but thank you anyways

Answer (score 1):

Try below code, just change my data to your data like images and texts.

your alert function:

```
 myalertFunction(BuildContext context) {
    return showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: const Text('Buy power up?'),
          content: Container(
            height: 300,
            child: Column(
               children: [
                Text('Do you want to buy'),
                ListTile(
                  leading: IconButton(
                      icon: Image.asset('assets/twitter.png'),
                      onPressed: () {}),
                  title: Text('TNT for 100\$'),
                ),
                ListTile(
                  leading: IconButton(
                      icon: Image.asset('assets/twitter.png'),
                      onPressed: () {}),
                  title: Text('Mine for 200\$'),
                ),
                ListTile(
                  leading: IconButton(
                      icon: Image.asset('assets/twitter.png'),
                      onPressed: () {}),
                  title: Text('Wrapped for 1000\$'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
       /*  actions: [
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            IconButton(
                icon: Image.asset('assets/twitter.png'), onPressed: () {}),
            IconButton(
                icon: Image.asset('assets/twitter.png'), onPressed: () {}),
            IconButton(
                icon: Image.asset('assets/twitter.png'), onPressed: () {}),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Text(
                'Start Game',
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],*/
          elevation: 24,
          shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(16))),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

Your Widget:

```
    TextButton(
          child: Text('Click Here'),
          onPressed: () {
            myalertFunction(context);
          }),
```

Result Screen-> [image] [image]

Comment: Thanks for your input, i think my question was not 100% clear, i do not want the Text to contain Buttons. The Buttons should stay on the bottom of the Alert Dialog, but thank you for your answer, i already solved the problem!
OK you edited your answer, this also works perfect now thank you very much!

Comment: If your problem has been solved by answer then accept it

Comment: One aditional question, is there a way to make the Image the same size as the text? Because currently i have to add a height to it manually like this: Image.asset('assets/images/bombs/tnt.png', height: 25)

Comment: @Felpower just give the `fontsize` of `text` same as image `height` like `IconButton(
                      icon: Image.asset('assets/twitter.png',height: 25,),
                      onPressed: () {}),
                  title: Text('TNT for 100\$',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25),),
                ),`   try this code

Answer (score 1):

You can use RichText

```
AlertDialog(
          title: const Text('Buy power up?'),
          content: RichText(
                text: TextSpan(
                  text: "Do you want to buy\n",
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                  children: [
                    WidgetSpan(
                        child: Image.asset('assets/images/bombs/tnt.png')),
                    TextSpan(text: 'for \$100\n',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
                    WidgetSpan(
                        child: Image.asset('assets/images/bombs/mine.png')),
                    TextSpan(text: 'for \$200\n',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
                    WidgetSpan(
                        child: Image.asset('assets/images/bombs/multi_color.png'),),
                    TextSpan(text: 'for \$300',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
                  ],
                ),
              ),,
          elevation: 24,
          shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(16))),
          actions: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
                icon: Image.asset('assets/images/bombs/tnt.png'),
                onPressed: () => buyPowerUp("tnt", tntPrice, coinBloc,
                    reportingBloc, gameBloc, context)),
            IconButton(
                icon: Image.asset('assets/images/bombs/mine.png'),
                onPressed: () => buyPowerUp("mine", minePrice, coinBloc,
                    reportingBloc, gameBloc, context)),
            IconButton(
                icon: Image.asset('assets/images/bombs/multi_color.png'),
                onPressed: () => buyPowerUp("wrapped", wrappedPrice,
                    coinBloc, reportingBloc, gameBloc, context)),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () => buyPowerUp(
                  "nothing", 0, coinBloc, reportingBloc, gameBloc, context),
              child: const Text('Start Game'),
            )
          ],
        ));
```

Comment: This works perfect, thank you very much, did not know about RichText!
The only thing is i have to add a "manual" height to the Image, is there a way to make the Image the same size as the text?

Comment: If you have an image size that is bigger then we need to provide manual values for that use WidgetSpan(child:Container(
width: 20,
height: 25
decoration: BoxDecoration(
image: DecorationImage(
fit: BoxFit. fill,
image: AssetImage("your image"), )) )
if you want to responsive use mediaquery to calculate and give the values for height and width factor